# Need to format text file and update based of key value format

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, string

I have a file having the below values:

cat data.txt

```
server1: calv
server2: anot
log: /u/log/1
server3: calv
server4: anot
server5: secd
server6: calv
LIB_TRGT_calv,anot: /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_TRGT_secd: /var/del.tmp
```

I get the variables starting with `LIB_TRGT` i.e `LIB_TRGT_calv,anot` & `LIB_TRGT_secd`

I need to get the names after `TRGT_` from the variable above i.e calv,anot.

considering we got `calv & anot`; I need to get all the entries having `calv` & `anot` and add the entries found in the data.txt as below:

Desired Output:

```
server1: calv
server2: anot
log: /u/log/1
server3: calv
server4: anot
server5: secd
server6: calv
LIB_TRGT_calv,anot: /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_TRGT_secd: /var/del.tmp
LIB_server1:  /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server2:  /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server3:  /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server4:  /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server6:  /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server5: /var/del.tmp
```

Likewise for `LIB_TRGT_secd`

Below is what I did so far:

```
grep TRGT* data.txt | cut -d: -f1 |cut -d_ -f3
calv,anot
secd
```

further

```
grep TRGT* test.txt | cut -d: -f1 |cut -d_ -f3 | sed -n 1'p' | tr ',' '\n'
calv
anot
```

However, `secd` is missing and i m not sure how to use `xargs` and further go about it.

Tried the solution by user @Kusalananda but it does not work. See output below:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the first TRGT line is `LIB_TRGT_calv,anot: /tmp/hello.txt` and not something like `LIB_TRGT_calv,LIB_TRGT_anot: /tmp/hello.txt`.?

Comment: i m sure it is `LIB_TRGT_calv,anot: /tmp/hello.txt`

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` program to do this, assuming the `LIB_TRGT_` lines always occur *after* the other lines that these refer to:

```c
BEGIN {
        FS = ":[[:blank:]]*"
        OFS = ": "
}

{ print }

$1 !~ /^LIB_TRGT_/ {
        # "list" is an associative array that uses the keys "calv",
        # "anot", and "secd", and for each of these stores the relevant
        # servers as a SUBSEP-delimited string.

        list[$2] = (list[$2] == "" ? $1 : list[$2] SUBSEP $1)
        next
}

{
        path = $2

        # Pick out the comma-delimited list of keys after "TRGT_", and
        # split these up into elements of the array "k".

        sub("^.*TRGT_", "", $1)
        nk = split($1, k, ",")

        $0 = ""
        $2 = path

        # For each key, get the corresponding list from "list" and
        # output the path for each of its values.

        for (i = 1; i <= nk; ++i) {
                nv = split(list[k[i]], v, SUBSEP)
                for (j = 1; j <= nv; ++j) {
                        $1 = "LIB_" v[j]
                        print
                }
        }
}
```

Testing, with the above script in the file `script`, and with your data in the *Unix text file* called `file`:

```bsh
$ awk -f script file
server1: calv
server2: anot
log: /u/log/1
server3: calv
server4: anot
server5: secd
server6: calv
LIB_TRGT_calv,anot: /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server1: /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server3: /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server6: /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server2: /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server4: /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_TRGT_secd: /var/del.tmp
LIB_server5: /var/del.tmp
```

The ordering is slightly different from what you show in the question due to reacting to the `LIB_TRGT_` lines as soon as they appear rather than saving them and handling them at the end.

Comment: How do I use this? I saved the awk script in a file called `script` and then tried this `awk -f script data.txt` but it does not work. Can you suggest please?

Comment: @Ashar "It does not work"? Well, then something is wrong. Unfortunately, I can't see what happens when you run that command, and as you can see in my answer, it is clearly working when I copy-and-paste your example data and use that as input. If your data file is a DOS text file (i.e. from a Windows system), you may want to convert it to a Unix text file using the `dos2unix` tool.

Comment: check my Original post showing your solution's output and let me know if I'm missing something?

Comment: @Ashar Yeah, your file `test.txt` is a DOS text file. Please convert it to a Unix text file.

Comment: No, I just created it using vi editor on the server. manually!!

Comment: @Ashar Ah, sorry, I see now. You have a number of spaces (or possibly a tab) at the start of each line.  These were not there in the question.  Either remove that indentation, or change `$1 !~ /^LIB_TRGT_/` in the code to `$1 !~ /LIB_TRGT_/` (remove a `^`).

Comment: @Ashar Actually, it would be better to just delete the indentation of the input data.  You can do that with changing `{ print }` to `{ sub("^[[:blank:]]*", ""); print }`.

Comment: What would be the solution if we were to only look for `_TRGT_` and not `LIB_TRGT_`? I tried `$1 !~ /_TRGT_/` but it does not work. Also, tried `$1 !~ /*_TRGT_/` that too fails.

Comment: @Ashar This does not seem to be part of the original question.

Comment: Sure, Can you suggest as i posted a new post here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700226/need-help-formatting-a-file-having-key-value

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this problem by means of generating code from the data and then applying that generated code to the data itself.

GNU sed with extended regex mode used.

```bsh
inputf='./data.txt'

< "$inputf" \
sed -E '
  s/^\s+|\s+$//g
  s/\s+/\t/g
' |
sed -E '
  /_TRGT_[^:\t]/{
    s/^(([^_]+_)+TRGT_)([^,:]+)[,:](.*(\t\S+))$/\3\5\n\1\4/
    h;s/\n.*//;s/.*\t//
    s:[\/&]:\\&:g;G
    s/(.*)\n(.*\t).*(\n.*)/\2\1\3/
    P
  }
  D
' |
sed -En '
  1i\
p

  s#(.*)\t(.*)#/:\\t\1$/{s/^/LIB_/;s/:.*/:\\t\2/;H;ba;}#p

  $a\
:a\
$!d;g;s/.//
' |
sed -Ef - "$inputf"

server1:    calv
server2:    anot
log:    /u/log/1
server3:    calv
server4:    anot
server5:    secd
server6:    calv
LIB_TRGT_calv,anot: /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_TRGT_secd:  /var/del.tmp
LIB_server1:    /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server2:    /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server3:    /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server4:    /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server5:    /var/del.tmp
LIB_server6:    /tmp/hello.txt
```

---

- Step0, clean the data by removing leading trailing whitespace. Monospace to TABs.
- Step1 we isolate the key value pairs, put them in one per line.
- Step2 armed with these kv tuples, we generate sed code.
- Step3, we apply the code to data.

Answer (score 0):

The below is a unified solution to both of your scenarios, viz., when the second fields are quoted or not.

```bsh
awk -v q=\' '1
NF<2{next}
!/^([^_]+_)+TRGT_/ {
  a[FNR] = $2
  b[FNR,$2] = $1
  if (index($2,q) == 1) quoted++
  next
}
{
  n = split($1, temp, /[_,:]/)
  s=0
  for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
    t = temp[i]
    s += length(t)+1
    ch = substr($1, s-1, 1)
    if (ch == "_") continue
    key = (!quoted) ? t : q t q
    c[key] = $2
  }
  split("", temp, ":")
}
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
END {
  for (i=1; i in a; i++)
    if ( (a[i] in c) && ((i SUBSEP a[i]) in b))
      print "LIB_"b[i,a[i]], c[a[i]]
}' data.txt

server1:    'calv'
server2:    'anot'
log:    '/u/log/1'
server3:    'calv'
server4:    'anot'
server5:    'secd'
server6:    'calv'
LIB_TRGT_calv,anot: '/tmp/hello.txt'
LIB_TRGT_secd:  '/var/del.tmp'
LIB_server1:    '/tmp/hello.txt'
LIB_server2:    '/tmp/hello.txt'
LIB_server3:    '/tmp/hello.txt'
LIB_server4:    '/tmp/hello.txt'
LIB_server5:    '/var/del.tmp'
LIB_server6:    '/tmp/hello.txt'
```

---