# Need help Formatting a file having key: value

Tags: awk, sed, string, text-formatting, yaml

I have a file having the below values:

cat data.txt

```
server1: 'calv'
server2: 'anot'
log: '/u/log/1'
server3: 'calv'
server4: 'anot'
server5: 'secd'
server6: 'calv'
LIB_TRGT_calv,anot: '/tmp/hello.txt'
LIB_TRGT_secd: '/var/del.tmp'
```

I get the variables containing `_TRGT_` i.e `LIB_TRGT_calv,anot` & `LIB_TRGT_secd`

Note: the names of the variable could be different like `DB_TRGT_<whatever>`

I need to get the names after `_TRGT_` from the variable above i.e `calv,anot` and `secd`.

considering we got `calv & anot & secd`; I now need to get all the entries having `calv` & `anot` & `secd` and add those found entries in the data.txt as below:

Desired Output:

```
server1: 'calv'
server2: 'anot'
log: '/u/log/1'
server3: 'calv'
server4: 'anot'
server5: 'secd'
server6: 'calv'
LIB_TRGT_calv,anot: '/tmp/hello.txt'
LIB_TRGT_secd: '/var/del.tmp'
LIB_server1:  '/tmp/hello.txt'
LIB_server2:  '/tmp/hello.txt'
LIB_server3:  '/tmp/hello.txt'
LIB_server4:  '/tmp/hello.txt'
LIB_server6:  '/tmp/hello.txt'
LIB_server5: '/var/del.tmp'
```

Below is what I did so far:

```
grep TRGT* data.txt | cut -d: -f1 |cut -d_ -f3
calv,anot
secd
```

further

```
grep TRGT* test.txt | cut -d: -f1 |cut -d_ -f3 | sed -n 1'p' | tr ',' '\n'
calv
anot
```

I m not sure how to use `xargs` and further go about it.

Comment: I see you have now added quotes to your values. Is the file in fact a YAML file?

Comment: Yes, It dumps a YAML

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/700210/133219) and why isn't your starting point the code from the previous answer you got?

Comment: This is different as the Solution provided in the previous works strictly for keys starting with `LIB_TRGT_` while here the requirement is `<anything>_TRGT_`. Also, the value here is enclosed in singlequotes `'`. Thus the solution there does not work here @Ed Morton

Comment: Then state THAT in your problem and provide THAT script as the starting point and reference your previous question for context, don't have us start all over again with a pile of greps, cuts, seds, etc. in a pipeline as if you hadn't already got most of the solution you need.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is YAML, I'd use a YAML parser, such as `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/

Given the input data in `file` and a short script in `script`:

```bsh
$ yq -y -f script file
server1: calv
server2: anot
log: /u/log/1
server3: calv
server4: anot
server5: secd
server6: calv
LIB_TRGT_calv,anot: /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_TRGT_secd: /var/del.tmp
LIB_server1: /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server2: /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server3: /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server4: /tmp/hello.txt
LIB_server5: /var/del.tmp
LIB_server6: /tmp/hello.txt
```

This was done using the following `jq` script (`yq` is a YAML wrapper around the `jq` JSON parser):

```
with_entries(
        select(.key | test("_TRGT_")) |
        .value as $v |
        .key | sub(".*_TRGT_"; "") | split(",")[] |
        { key: ., value: $v }
) as $map |
. += with_entries(
        select(.value | in($map)) |
        { key: ("LIB_" + .key), value: $map[.value] }
)
```

This first computes the JSON object `$map`, which, given the data in the question, will be a simple map between the special key values, parsed out from the `_TRGT_` keys in the original data, and the pathnames:

```json
{                         
  "calv": "/tmp/hello.txt",
  "anot": "/tmp/hello.txt",
  "secd": "/var/del.tmp"
}
```

For each value in the original data that corresponds to a key in this `$map` object, a new entry is created with the key computed from value's key and the value taken from the corresponding entry in `$map`.