# split string using a substring as delimiter and get the later part

Tags: awk, sed, string, text-formatting, cut

Here is my string `LIBRARY_TRGT_CANV,CANV_MATCH<anything>`

I wish to get all the text after last occurance of our delimiter which is `_TRGT_`:

Desired output:

`CANV,CANV_MATCH<anything>`

------ OR -----

get all the text after second underscore i.e `CANVL,CANVL_BATCH<anything>`

Comment: Isn't this a subtask of your recent question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700226/need-help-formatting-a-file-having-key-value) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700210/need-to-format-text-file-and-update-based-of-key-value-format)? I suggest you focus into one post to get actual help.

Answer (score 3):

No `sed` or `awk` needed for that; you can do it in any pure POSIX shell.

Assuming you have the string as variable `$string`, you can get everything after the last `_TRGT_` with:

```
cutstring="${string##*_TRGET_}"
```

(`##` to remove the longest possible match at the start of the string)

To get everything after 2nd underscore:

```
cutstring="${string#*_*_}"
```

(`#` to remove the shortest possible match at the start of the string)

Of course, you can do it with `sed` as well; to get what's after last `_TRGT_`:

```
sed 's/.*_TRGT_//' <<< "$string"
```

Or to get what's after the second underscore:

```
sed 's/^[^_]*_[^_]*_//' <<< "$string"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "LIBRARY_TRGT_CANV,CANV_MATCH<anything>"|awk -F "_TRGT_" '{print $NF}'
```

output

```
CANV,CANV_MATCH<anything>
```